# How does memchr() work under the hood?

Tags: c, performance, d, standard-library

**Background:**  I'm trying to create a pure D language implementation of functionality that's roughly equivalent to [C's memchr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memchr) but uses arrays and indices instead of pointers.  The reason is so that std.string will work with compile time function evaluation.  For those of you unfamiliar w/ D, functions can be evaluated at compile time if certain restrictions are met.  One restriction is that they can't use pointers.  Another is that they can't call C functions or use inline assembly language.  Having the string library work at compile time is useful for some compile time code gen hacks.

**Question:**  How does memchr work under the hood to perform as fast as it does?  On Win32, anything that I've been able to create in pure D using simple loops is at least 2x slower even w/ obvious optimization techniques such as disabling bounds checking, loop unrolling, etc.  What kinds of non-obvious tricks are available for something as simple as finding a character in a string?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)'s source. As for most functions, it will contain both a generic optimized C version of the function, and optimized assembly language versions for as many supported architectures as possible, taking advantage of machine specific tricks.

The [x86-64 SSE2 version](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/x86_64/memchr.S) combines the results from [`pcmpeqb`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PCMPEQB:PCMPEQW:PCMPEQD.html) on a whole cache-line of data at once (four 16B vectors), to amortize the overhead of the early-exit `pmovmskb`/`test`/`jcc`.

gcc and clang are currently incapable of auto-vectorizing loops with `if() break` early-exit conditions, so they make naive byte-at-a-time asm from the obvious C implementation.

Comment: Thanks, except this is LGPL code and D's standard library is supposed to be permissively licensed.  I don't want that to be an issue.

Comment: Well, I was suggesting you look at it for technique inspiration, rather than for copying the source.

Comment: It is roughly 150 lines of code, about half or more of which are comments, so it explains the optimizations in a fair amount of detail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405208/gpl-code-what-counts-as-a-derivative-work  I'm the OP on this question.

Comment: I've read that question before, and it's a good question. The answer is that you can't copyright techniques, only the code itself. Also, the FSF are vehemently proposed to software patents or the idea that algorithms and ideas can be effectively copyrighted and their use restricted.

Answer (score 7):

[This implementation of memchr from newlib](https://sourceware.org/viewvc/src/newlib/libc/string/memchr.c?revision=1.4&view=markup) is one example of someone's optimizing memchr:
it's reading and testing 4 bytes at a time (apart from memchr, other functions in the newlib library are [here](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/newlib/libc/string/?cvsroot=src)).

Incidentally, most of the the source code for the MSVC run-time library is available, as an optional part of the MSVC installation (so, you could look at that).

Comment: i was going to answer with the newlib code of memchr - until i clicked your link and saw it's also about newlib :)

Comment: if you like, you can link them to this: http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/newlib/libc/string/?cvsroot=src , cvs directory containing all the sweet fast string functions of newlib, including memchr.c

Comment: URL has [changed to this](https://sourceware.org/viewvc/src/newlib/libc/string/memchr.c?revision=1.4&view=markup)

Answer (score 6):

Here is FreeBSD's (BSD-licensed) memchr() from [**memchr.c**](http://svn.freebsd.org/viewvc/base/stable/7/lib/libc/string/memchr.c?view=markup). FreeBSD's online source code browser is a good reference for time-tested, BSD-licensed code examples.

```
void *
memchr(s, c, n)
    const void *s;
    unsigned char c;
    size_t n;
{
    if (n != 0) {
        const unsigned char *p = s;

        do {
            if (*p++ == c)
                return ((void *)(p - 1));
        } while (--n != 0);
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I found this too.  Nothing fancy here, though, that would explain the ridiculous speed difference.

Answer (score 2):

memchr like memset and memcpy generally reduce to fairly small amount of machine code.   You are unlikely to be able to reproduce that kind of speed without [inlining similar assembly code](http://sourceware.org/ml/newlib/2008/msg00290.html).  One major issue to consider in an implementation is [data alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packed).

One [generic technique you may be able to use](http://smallcode.weblogs.us/sentinel_for_string_manipulations) is to insert a [sentinel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_(computer_science)) at the end of the string being searched, which guarantees that you will find it.   It allows you to move the test for end of string from inside the loop, to after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

GNU libc definitely uses the **assembly** version of memchr() (on any common linux distro). This is why it is so unbelievable fast.
 For example, if we count lines in 11Gb file (like "*wc -l*" does) it takes around **2.5** seconds with **assembly** version of memchr() from GNU libc. But if we replace memchr() assembly call with for example memchr() **C implementation** from FreeBSD - the speed will decrease to like **30** seconds.
 This is equal to replacing memchr() with just a while loop which compares one char after another.