# Fastest way to find first occurrence of byte in buffer

Tags: c++

*Disclaimer*

- *I have read [What is the fastest substring search algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183582/what-is-the-fastest-substring-search-algorithm), which may be suboptimal for the single character case.*
- *`strchr` requires a NUL-terminated string*

---

I am looking for the fastest way to identify the first occurrence of a given byte in a byte buffer.

This is reminiscent of looking for the first occurrence of a character in a string except that:

- the byte buffer is not NUL-terminated, instead I have an explicit length (and possibly embedded NUL characters)
- the byte buffer is not allocated in a `string` or `vector`, I am only handed down a *slice* (aka, pointer & length)

The basic solution is:

```
size_t search(char const* buffer, size_t length, char c) {
    return std::find(buffer, buffer + length, c) - buffer;
}
```

However, a quick round-trip with the Godbolt compiler (`-O2 -msse2 -mavx`) does not show any hint of a vectorized instruction, only some unrolling, so I am wondering whether this is the optimal.

Is there a faster way to find the first occurrence of a given byte in a buffer?

*Note: only the first occurrence matters.*

*Note: I am exclusively concerned with modern x86_64 CPUs on Linux, though I encourage answers to be as generic as possible and mention assumptions clearly.*

Comment: Maybe try [`memchr`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memchr) - it's like `strchr` but it doesn't require a NUL-terminated string ?

Comment: It’s dismaying that `std::find` isn’t optimised to take advantage of compiler intrinsics on GCC. Somebody should write a patch, it’s such an obvious optimisation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I am quite surprised as well, especially since according to David Haim the optimization is done on VC++. Maybe a concern about inlining? (As in, a pure C++ implementation can be compile-time evaluated, an assembly one cannot)

Comment: @MatthieuM. at least on VC++, all the `strXXX` and `memXXX` functions will be compile-time evaluated on compile time if the data is known on compile time. I don't think it's a technical issue that prevent GCC from using it

Comment: @DavidHaim: Ah, probably because resolving to intrinsics, the compiler knows what their functionality is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `memchr` , which is usually implemented as an intrinsic function, and is usually (from my experience) much faster than any hand-rolled loop.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memchr

Edit: at least on VC++ (and I bet on GCC as well, I haven't checked), `std::find` will use `memchr` anyway if you look for a byte , so I would check if `memchr` actually make the program run faster.

Comment: An explanation of `memchr` implementation can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525123/how-does-memchr-work-under-the-hood). Notes from [BurntSushi's Rust memchr crate](https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-memchr/blob/master/src/lib.rs) hint that libc's `memchr` is slowish on Windows though.

Comment: From Godbolt, no, `std::find` on a `char` is not reduced to a `memchr` by gcc (6.2).

Comment: @MatthieuM. so here is a something to try out :)

Comment: Yes, it's a really good contender certainly; especially since I don't have to care about Windows compatibility in my case.